# Angular 4 - link values from api to component and template

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bind-html, angular2-ngmodel

In Angular 4 application, I have table with rows. I have to integrate each row with list-view component, so it shows up correctly in webpage. list view component shows status as success - color green, warning - color red ,info - color blue.

```
<list-view [status]="success"></list-view>
```

this returns list view with green color.

but API returns value as Draft,Not Changed, Error. I am not getting how to map values from api to value that template understands.

where data is = `"Data":[ {id:1, status:"draft"}, {id:2,status:"Not Changed"},{id:3,status:"Error"} ]`

html -

```
 <ng-container   *ngFor="let data of Data">                       
 <tr style="margin-top: 8px !important;">
<list-view  [status]="{{data.status}}"></adp-list-view>
```

here status returns as Draft, but i have change it in component to success, so my template works with expected output.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question / issue. It should be `[status]="data.status"` though since `[]` already does input property binding.

Comment: @ExplosionPills i have kept in {{}} bcoz im getting status value from api, but yes withou it also its fine.

Comment: No, that syntax will throw a template parse error. You can't have attribute binding `[]` and interpolation syntax `{{ }}` in the same statement.

Comment: can you post how you're retrieving the data? Are you unwrapping the async call to a component property `Data`?